# Qemu Network Options: tap vs bridge

Tags: networking, qemu, bridge, tun-tap

I just started learning how to use Qemu for a project. I was trying to run Qemu using using bridge networking and was wondering what is the difference between the network options, tap and bridge.

I read the network options part in the Qemu document but is unable to understand the difference. The document mention that "-netdev tap" is use to configure a host TAP network backend with ID id while "-netdev bridge" is use to connect a host TAP network interface to a host bridge device. I also look at this website: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/QEMU#Tap_networking_with_QEMU, but was still unable to understand the difference between using "-netdev tap" vs "-netdev bridge".

Can anyone help me by explaining the differences between using "-netdev tap" and "-netdev bridge" for Qemu?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I am solving the same problem, and until now I did not find much diferences. Formerly I expected that bridge uses shorten TUN way (OSI level 3 - IP), but after I've succesfully configured two VM to be connected with `-netdev bridge` I found that qemu helper added two TAP dummy interfaces in host system and connected them to an existing bridge interface. After I 'poweroff' both VM, the qemu helper disconnected and deleted the TAP interfaces automaticaly.

Fo me this means that `bridge` saves my config time, but the result is the same as by use the `tap` . I can admit, the TAP configuration needs much attention, time and commands, hence I see `-netdev bridge` as more comfortable way. The TAP may offer more featueres, but I cannot appreciate them now.

There left a question about the *capacity* of the host kernel bridge. I did not find any limit for connected interfaces to a single `br0` device (just feeling the bridge connects two watersides only, but who knows). I just read that more features gives the Open Virtual Switch, but I am not sure if I really need it.

Answer (score 0):

They both provide different command line interfaces to use TAP as the network backend for the guest to connect to a host bridge. The TAP netdev allows for a finer degree of control of the TAP device that is used but in both cases the network path is the same. This is in contrast to user-mode networking which allows networking without privileged access to the host network stack albeit with some limitations on the sort of packets that can be sent.